# Only allow one URL to access a website. Block all ofters in .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

I have a site (example.com) and on that site I have an iframe. I want that frame to bring in a site (site2.com) but not allow anyone else from directly accessing that site (site2.com) directly.

This .htacces code works on (example.com) but is only bring in the homepage of (site2.com)

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^https://example.com/$
    RewriteRule index.php - [F,NC]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: _"but is only bring in the homepage of (site2.com)"_ - what is that supposed to mean?

Comment: _"This .htacces code works on (example.com)"_ - you want to allow or deny access on site2.com, so it needs to be handled on _that_ end.

Comment: I want to deny direct access to the site2.com from everywhere except the iframe in example.com

Comment: Again, first of all, that would have to be handled on the site2.com side of things. And second - the referrer would also be set to that value, if the user simply clicked a _link_ on example.com, pointing to site2.com, instead of viewing it via an iframe - so if you would absolutely need to differentiate between _those_ two scenarios as well, a mere referrer check won't do.

Comment: Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: The above, implemented _on_ site2, should do it already, for the most part. You might want to allow a completely empty referrer as an alternative, in case that got blocked for privacy reasons. If you are in control of example.com, then the difference between link vs iframe, should probably not be all to relevant? Not _setting_ any such links on example.com, should be under your purview then.

Comment: If you want anything more than a fragile, referrer-based solution - then you will need to program something on both sides, like maybe that example.com creates some sort of token, that gets passed via the URL, and that site2 can verify ...